# Error in Azure SQL Database connection with Azure AD Service Principals using Azure Datapreb library

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-functions

I am trying to connect Azure SQL database with Azure AD Service Principals using the azure datapreb library.

**Please check the below code :-**

```
import logging
import struct
from . import hy_param
import azureml.dataprep as dprep
import azure.functions as func
import adal

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    try:
        SQL_COPT_SS_ACCESS_TOKEN = 1256
        # connection string for database connection without username and password
        connection_string = "Driver=" + hy_param.sql_driver + ';SERVER=' + hy_param.server_name + ';DATABASE=' + hy_param.database_name

        token = get_token()
        conn = dprep.MSSQLDataSource(connection_string, attrs_before = { SQL_COPT_SS_ACCESS_TOKEN:token})
        logging.info("Connection is : ",conn)
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        # # Read data from table
        cursor.execute("SELECT GETDATE()")
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Created :- {row}",
            status_code=200
        )
    except Exception as e:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Error in sql database connection : {e}", status_code=400)

def get_token():
    # get token using the Azure AD Service Principals
    authority_url = (hy_param.login_url + '/' + hy_param.tenant_id)

    context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authority_url, api_version=None)
    access_token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(hy_param.resource_url, hy_param.client_id, hy_param.client_secret)

    converted_token = bytes(access_token["accessToken"], "UTF-8")
    operated_token = b''
    for each_token_data in converted_token:
        operated_token += bytes({each_token_data})
        operated_token += bytes(1)
    token_data = struct.pack("=i", len(operated_token)) + operated_token
    return token_data
```

**Please check the below error :-**

```
Error in sql database connection : __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs_before'
```

**Is there any way to solve the above problem? I want to access the Azure SQL DB using Datapreb library with Azure AD Service Principals.**

I tried it on Pyodb library and it's works fine but not on datapreb library.

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying this line it’s unhappy about and doesn’t recognize this parameter.  What version of the library are you using and is it possible that it in fact does not accept a parameter named this or renamed (attrs_before)?

`conn = dprep.MSSQLDataSource(connection_string, attrs_before = { SQL_COPT_SS_ACCESS_TOKEN:token})`

Comment: Yes, i got the above point, but I want to access the Azure SQL database using Service Principals with the azure Datapreb library.